# App Script variable always holding up the previous data of google sheet's cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Working with google sheets. Developed a form where a variable from app script will take data from a cell in google sheet. But variable always holding up current value. If I change the value in the cell of the sheet variable cant fetch that changed value.

```
function Search() {
 
  var SS= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ShtRecords= SS.getSheetByName("Records");
  var ShtForm= SS. getSheetByName("Form");
  var records= ShtRecords.getDataRange().getValues();
  var sField= ShtForm.getRange("A2").getValue();
  var sValue= ShtForm.getRange("A6").getValue();
  var SCol= records[0].lastIndexOf(sField);
  Logger.log(sValue); 
  var Results= records.filter(function(e){return sValue==e[SCol]});

  if (Results.length == 0) {SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("value not found");}
  else {
    ShtForm.getRange(2,3,Results.length,Results[0].length).setValues(Results);
  }
}
```

sValue always fetching the previous value. How I can get the changed value in sheets in sValue?

[Changing A6 value from blank to 223](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DsL6.jpg)
After changing A6 value I tried to run search function. But variable always used to fetch null value which was the previous value [variable isnt changing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtgsw.jpg)

Comment: Please provide sample data so that users can reproduce the problem that you have described.

Comment: Add more logging to your script when testing to so you can see what isn't working and where.  Also `SS. getSheetByName("Form")` has a space that shouldn't be there.